# How come modifying and running a stored procedure "fixes" it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

So I had this stored procedure that searches through a bunch of companies, that suddenly started to be really slow (20-30 seconds on 4000 rows, two columns selected).

The problem is fixed, but I don't understand why.

The thing I did, was, I went into SQL server management studio and modified the stored procedure - running the alter SP statement, but not actually editing anything the SP did.

Now it's blazing fast as it should be, barely taking miliseconds.

My question is, why the hell did that fix it? I didn't edit anything in the SP itself, I only altered it to it's current state.

Comment: To add to Dr Smith's comment, have a look at the `WITH RECOMPILE` option when you create the SP. It will force compilation of the SP every time it is run. Only you can tell if it provides a net improvement in performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By recommitting a stored procedure, you force a recompilation of it; this also clears any cached query plans for it. If a stored procedure uses a lot of conditional logic, the query plan may be cached for an atypical query, compared to your slow ones